# Logging out user from Subversive in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, subversive

I stupidly checked "remember settings" when logging during commiting to repository. I'm using Subversive plug-in for eclipse. I was working on my brother's computer, who is also working on my project. I wonder if there is any chance for him to log in, so he could commit changes as himself, not as me.

Comment: Sure, log out of Subversion and have your brother log in.  Simple.

Comment: I don't use Eclipse, but there must be a way in the client to do it.  Clearing the authentication cache comes to mind.  That's how I'd do it in IntelliJ, the best IDE on the market.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subclipse does not collect or store username and password credentials when defining a repository. This is because the JavaHL and SVNKit client adapters are intelligent enough to prompt you for this information when they need to -- including when your password has changed.

You can also allow the adapter to cache this information and a common question is how do you delete this cached information so that you can be prompted again? We have an open request to have an API added to JavaHL so that we could provide a UI to do this. Currently, you have to manually delete the cache. The location of the cache varies based on the client adapter used.

JavaHL caches the information in the same location as the command line client -- in the Subversion runtime configuration area. On Windows this is located in %APPDATA%\Subversion\auth. On Linux and OSX it is located in ~/.subversion/auth. Just find and delete the file with the cached information.

SVNKit caches information in the Eclipse keyring. By default this is a file named .keyring that is stored in the root of the Eclipse configuration folder. Both of these values can be overriden with command line options. To clear the cache, you have to delete the file. Eclipse will create a new empty keyring when you restart.

This text if copied from [here](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/PluginFAQ#head-d507c29676491f4419997a76735feb6ef0aa8cf8)

You can prefer to read it from there itself.

Comment: well, I don't have a single file stored in %APPDATA%\Subversion :/ Hidden or not

Comment: then I guess your settings are not saved.

Comment: well, it doesn't prompt for user... just commits from the one I've entered once